# Basis and change of co-ordinate matrix for $\mathbb P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> a) Find a basis for $\mathbb P_2$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix}p(0) \\ p(1) \\ p(2) \end{bmatrix}$$ are the co-ordinates of any polynomial $p$ with respect to that basis.
>
> b) Find a basis for $\mathbb P_2$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\p'(0)\\p''(0)\end{bmatrix}$$ are the co-ordinates of any polynomial $p$ with respect to that basis.
>
> c) Find the co-ordinates of $p(x) = x^2$ in both these co-ordinate systems.
>
> d)Find the change of co-ordinate matrix between these co-ordinate systems. That is, find a matrix $A$ such that $$A\begin{bmatrix}p(0) \\ p(1) \\ p(2) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\p'(0)\\p''(0)\end{bmatrix}$$ For any $p$ in $\mathbb P_2$.

For a) I thought of the bases $a_0,a_0 +a_1 +a_2,a_0 +2a_1 +4a_2$

for b) I though of the bases $a_0,a_1+2a_2 x,2a_2$

Not sure how to find the co-ordinates of $p(x) = x^2$ in these co-ordinate systems though (I suspect my bases are wrong). Also not sure how to do part d).

Comment: Sorry, but your "bases" are indeed wrong, because they are not even bases. In both (a) and (b) you need to find **bases**, not *matrices*. So you probably should start with setting up the definition of what a **basis** is.

Comment: Ok so i rephrased my post a bit. Should make more sense now.

Comment: Still no... Once again, I strongly recommend that you set up the definition of a basis of a vector space. I literally mean that you should write it down and read it carefully, because that should tell you what you are supposed to find in questions (a) and (b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the elements in a basis for $P_2$ must be a member of $P_2$ i.e. a quadratic polynomial.

For part (a), the $p(0)$ element of the basis should be a quadratic polynomial such that $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1)=p(2)=0$. $(x-1)(x-2)$ satisfies the second condition, and to satisfy the first condition we can divide by two, so the first element of the basis is $\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{2}$. You can use a similar method to find the other two basis elements.

The co-ordinates of $x^2$ in the part (a) basis are just the values of $p(x)=x^2$ at 0, 1 and 2 i.e. $(0,1,4)$.

For part (b) the basis is $(1, x, \frac{1}{2}x^2)$. Note that the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is required so that $p''(0)=1$. The co-ordinates of $x^2$ in this basis are then $(0,0,2)$.

For part (d) you can form each column of the 3x3 matrix A by finding the co-ordinates of each of the basis elements from part (a) relative to the part (b) basis. For example, the co-ordinates of $p(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{2}$ relative to the part (b) basis are $(p(0),p'(0),p''(0)) = (1,\frac{-3}{2},1)$, so the first column of A is $(1,\frac{-3}{2},1)$.

You can validate your result for part (d) by checking that your A matrix correctly converts the co-ordinates of $x^2$ (from part (c)) from one basis to the other.

Comment: Why is it that we must demand $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1) = p(2) = 0$ for a)? Also i don't see how you can get $x^2$ in a) when plugging in numerical values for $x$ If you plug in values for $x$ theres no $x's$ in the expression. For b) i don't see how you can differentiate a function two times and get an $x^2$ term. I also don't see why $p''(0)$ has to equal 1. Also shouldn't the bases in $b)$ also be quadratic polynomials?

Comment: @Pame - part (a) - we want the first basis element to have co-ordinates (1,0,0). Hence $p(0)=1$ and $p(1)=p(2)=0$. We want the second basis vector to have co-ordinates (0,1,0) so for this element $p(1)=0$ and $p(0)=p(2)=0$ etc.

Comment: @Pame - part (b) - we want the third basis element to have co-ordinates (0,0,1), so $p(0)=p'(0)=0$ and $p''(0)=1$. For a general quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ we have $p(0)=c$, $p'(0)=b$ and $p''(0)=2a$. So we set $b=c=0$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$. As long as each basis element is a polynomial with degree <= 2, this fine - they do not all have to have a non-zero $x^2$ term.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

This kind of problems are easily solved remembering that:

> the components of a vector with respect to  a basis are the inner products of  the vector with the corresponding element of the basis.

This implies that, if $p(x)=p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2$ is the vector $\vec p$ that in the standard basis has  components $\vec p=(p_0,p_1,p_2)^T$, and we want a basis where the components are $(p(0),p(1),p(2))^T=(p_0,p_0+p_1+p_2,p_0+2p_1+4p_2)^T$ we have to find the vectors (of the basis) $\{\vec u,\vec v, \vec w\}$ such that:

$$
\langle \vec u,\vec p\rangle=p_0 \qquad \langle \vec v,\vec p\rangle=p_0+p_1+p_2 \quad \langle \vec w,\vec p\rangle=p_0+2p_1+4p_2
$$

can you see what the vectors (and polynomials) $\{\vec u,\vec v, \vec w\}$ are in the standard basis?

And in a similari way you can solve the other problem.

Comment: What does the notation $(p(0),p(1),p(2))^T$ mean? Specifically the $T$. Also not sure what $
\langle \vec u,\vec p\rangle=p_0$ really means and how you came to figure it out.

Comment: $T$ means the ''transpose'' so $(p(0),p(1),p(2))^T$ is your vector of components $p(0)$, $p(1)$ and $p(2)$ .

Comment: $\langle \vec u,\vec p \rangle=p_0$ means that the component of the vector $\vec p$ with respect to the basis vector $\vec u$ is $p_0$.